# Why this code is not running for infinite time?

Tags: python, arrays, append, range, infinite-loop

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4,5]
total = len(my_array)
for value in range(total):
    print(my_array[value])    
    my_array.append(value*value)
    total = len(my_array)
print(my_array)
```

If you attach the debugger and see the value will increase for the variable "total"

Comment: What's the desired behaviour you are looking for here?

Comment: range(total) is likely generated once at the beginning of the for loop!

Answer (score 1):

`range(total)` is only evaluated once, at the beginning of the loop. It's not re-evaluated after each iteration. Thus, the loop will only run 5 times, despite `total` going up inside of it.

Comment: Yes got it. But why the debugger shows the incremented value?(It should remain constant )

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: While I was debugging it incremented the value on each iteration but terminated in 5 times. The value of "total" incremented till 10

Comment: That's exactly what my answer explains.

Comment: Understood.Thanks very much